# marginalising probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given that

$\sum_b p(a|b)p(b) = p(a)$

and its extension

$\sum_b p(a|b,c)p(b,c)=p(a,c)=p(a|c)p(c)$

can I say anything about the following

$\sum_b p(a|b,c)p(a,b)$?

Whilst I clearly can't express the new expression as a total probability to marginalise over, can the nuisance variable be marginalised away generically like the last form of the second example to give $p(a|c)p(a)$?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Note that for the second we have $\sum_b p(a\mid b,c)p(b,c) = \sum_b p(a,c\mid b)p(b)=p(a,c)$

For the third, $\sum_b p(a\mid b,c)p(a,b)$ , we can't do anything of the sort.